# Missing parameter after state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have simple application with 3 states:

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
            'view': {
              templateUrl: 'modules/view/view.html',
              controller: 'MainCtrl'
            }
    }
    }).state('orgmissing', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
                   'view': {
                   templateUrl: 'modules/view/noOrg.html',
                   controller: 'MainCtrl'
                }
        }
    }).state('main.add', {
        url: '/add',
        views: {
            'formContainer': {templateUrl: "modules/view/form-container.html", controller: "TimetableCtrl"},
        }
    });
```

I'm starting application with parameter '/timetable/?org=org:1'. 
Everything seems to work fine until I'm changing states. 
After going to 'main.add' state url changes to '/timetable//add' - that's fine - i have parameter saved. But after refreshing page - it goes to 'orgmissing' state.

So my question is. Is there a way to keep parameter in url after changing states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the parameter in the url of the `main.add` state:

```
url: '/add?org
```

Then you can access it using `$stateParams.org` from `TimetableCtrl`

Comment: Thanks, for reply. It's not the clue of the problem, but i found workaround thanks to your's suggestion.
I've changed url to "url: '/add?org='" and then changed state.go to $state.go('main.add',$scope.orgContext).